# How to fix nodeos.logs showing "chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase."

Tags: nodeos

After following the guide to start my local node [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software) I issue the commands

```
brew tap eosio/eosio
brew install eosio

keosd &

nodeos -e -p eosio \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--access-control-allow-origin='*' \
--contracts-console \
--http-validate-host=false \
--verbose-http-errors >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &

tail -f nodeos.log
```

And normally the logs show blocks being produced.

Earlier today i did run

`brew upgrade eosio` to update to eosio 1.8.0

```
info  2019-07-08T10:41:51.809 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'FIX_LINKAUTH_RESTRICTION' (with digest of 'e0fb64b1085cc5538970158d05a009c24e276fb94e1a0bf6a528b48fbc4ff526') is enabled with preactivation required
info  2019-07-08T10:41:51.809 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:395          operator()           ] Support for builtin protocol feature 'GET_SENDER' (with digest of 'f0af56d2c5a48d60a4a5b5c903edfb7db3a736a94ed589d0b797df33ff9d3e1d') is enabled with preactivation required
warn  2019-07-08T10:41:51.820 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:958          plugin_initialize    ] 13 N5boost10wrapexceptISt13runtime_errorEE: chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase.
rethrow chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase.: 
    {"what":"chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase."}
    thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:958 plugin_initialize
error 2019-07-08T10:41:51.820 thread-0  main.cpp:114                  main                 ] 13 N5boost10wrapexceptISt13runtime_errorEE: chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase.
rethrow chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase.: 
    {"what":"chainbase database format not compatible with this version of chainbase."}
    thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:958 plugin_initialize
```

This far I have completely relied on brew to manage my install, is there a brew command to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chainbase database generated by nodeos v1.7.x or earlier isn't compatible with nodeos v1.8.x. You need to replay blockchain. Delete `data/state` and `data/blocks/reversible` from your `--data-dir` path, and run nodeos with `--replay-blockchain` option.
If your nodeos is connected to mainnet, it will take multiple days or weeks to replay from the genesis. You can find detailed instructions from [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/consensus-protocol-upgrade-process).

Comment: Thanks @conr2d I'm on a mac do you know where I can find the data-dir or if there is a command that will show it me?

Comment: @Bill You may find it from `~/Library/Application Support/eosio/nodeos/data`. I'm using nodeos on Ubuntu, so not possible to verify this answer. If right, please leave a comment for other Mac users :)

Comment: Yes that is the correct location on mac